# " no tests found with test runner 'Junit 4' "

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

Hello I am going to login into Guru99 page using TestNG Priorities.
While runnning the program getting the error as no tests found with test runner 'Junit 4'.Please help me how to resolve this issue and why it will come.

```
package Test_Pack1;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Test_Ng {

    WebDriver driver;
    @Test
    public void openBrowser() 
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                 "G:\\Selenium_Test\\lib\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();    
        driver.get("http://www.demo.guru99.com/V4/");
    }

    @Test(priority=1)

    public void peformSeachAndClick1stLink() 

    {
        driver.findElement(By.name("uid")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.name("uid")).sendKeys("mngr83102");
        driver.findElement(By.name("password")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("AregYme");
       // driver.findElement(By.name("uid")).sendKeys("mngr83102");
        //driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("AregYme");
        driver.findElement(By.name("btnLogin")).click();


    }

    //@Test
    @Test(priority=2)
    public void test()
    {
        String excepectedOutput = "Guru99 Bank";
        String actualOutput=driver.findElement(By.className("barone")).getText();
        System.out.println(actualOutput);       
        if(excepectedOutput.equalsIgnoreCase(actualOutput))
                    System.out.println("Test Passed");

        else
            System.out.println("Failed");

    }
        //@Test
        @Test(priority=3)
        public void quit()
        {

            driver.quit();

    }


}
```

Comment: How are you running the test class?

Answer (score 0):

Few things seems to be wrong here :

1. By default Maven uses the following naming conventions when looking for tests to run:
   Test*
   *Test
   *TestCase
   Your test class doesn't follow these conventions. You should rename it or configure Maven Surefire Plugin to use another pattern for test classes.
2. unit test code should put under the test folder, it can not be recognized as test class if you put it under the main folder. eg.

**Wrong**
/my_program/src/main/java/NotTest.java

**Right**
/my_program/src/test/java/MyTest.java

3. Also, check if your test classes directory (e.g. src/test/java) corresponds to directory listed in property  in your pom.xml under  property. Took me a while to find that.
4. Add assertion in order to identify it as a valid test to see the count on the terminal while running

Let me know, if you still face any issue or any of the solution did worked ?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.As I am at learning stage.I am not able to understand the words you are saying.Can you please tell me what it is....

Comment: Can you be specific, what you didn't understand ?

Comment: Hello Anshul,As I am using testNG annonations in selenium and i didin't understand the naming convensions.Also what us unit test code in current program. What exactly second point is where it should be refelcting.